# How To Make a bold unread Message in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

how to insert a navbar unread bold I'm using javascript inside.html the bold function is not working can you guys help me with the answer?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSideBarCount() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Supervisor/GetSideBarCount',
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json",
            beforeSend: function () { },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.notice != 0) {
                    $('.spn-notice-count').text(data.notice).show();
                    $('.spn-notice').html('<i class="text-danger fas fa-exclamation-circle mr-0"></i> ' + data.notice + '<b>NOTICE</b>').show();
                }
                else {
                    $('.spn-notice-count,.spn-notice').hide();
                }
```

Comment: Please remove **c#** tag

Comment: What "bold function"?

Comment: inside the .html

Comment: So you're saying that the word `NOTICE` does not show up in bold?

Comment: yes when i try to use bold function it should work for the unread message bold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make bold text use `<b>` and `</b>` tags.

Comment: it didn't work it should be an unread bold function in ajax